# "Your time is close enough" notification

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, processes

I am running Android Jelly bean 4.2.1 on my phone. Once in a while, I get this notification "Your time is close enough" with an android emoticon. This notification then disappears without any explanation what is happening. I searched the internet and saw some other people also got the same notification but no one knows why this happens. Can someone explain what this might be?

Comment: When you say notification, you mean in the notification bar at the top? Or a "toast" message? What device do you have? Are you rooted? Custom ROM? I know this isn't really an answer but I wasn't allowed to comment as I have too low reputation.

Comment: It's just in the notification bar. I am using a Samsung galaxy s3. It is not rooted, no custom rom (I don't even know what that is).

Comment: Have you tried pressing on the notification when its displayed? Or does it disappear too quickly to manage this?

Comment: When I pull down my notification menu, nothing appears there. The notification stays in the bar for the same time as other notifications.

Comment: This is creepy. But seriously, have you tried press-and-holding the notification and tapping 'App info'?

Comment: I tried press-and-holding the notification bar but nothing opens. Its just a notification with no visually no app running so I can't look at the App info. Maybe its some sort of virus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if you are using "GPS-provided time" in your Date and time Settings

I think it is an improper translation of "Your time is more accurate"

it may be due to some Adware too.Did you try holding the notification and see the "App info" of the notification?

Comment: yup, makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue i was in search of answer to that but i found out it is not a malware and we ourself enable it on android devices it is an auto update time check nothing to worry about.
If you want to get rid of it, just watch the procedure here 
http://www.technono.com/your-time-is-close-enough.html